# Python Numeric String to time conversion

Tags: python, time

I am trying to convert the string into the time,

```
 i have the following string,

 0100 will have to give time 01:00:00
 0130 will have to give time 01:30:00 likewise,
```

Anyone have an idea i am trying this

```
from datetime import datetime
import time

p = "0100"
op = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(float(p)) )
```

is giving me output like 00:01:40

how could i achieve my desired results

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`time.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) to format a string representing a time and then convert it back to the desired format using [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime):

```
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.strptime("0100", "%H%M"))
'01:00:00'
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.strptime("0130", "%H%M"))
'01:30:00'
>>> time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.strptime("2130", "%H%M"))
'21:30:00'
```